# Specific choice of rules of inference for predicate calculus

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

In Kleene's "Mathematical Logic" and "Introduction to Metamathematics" for a classical predicate calculus the following two rules of inference are chosen.

If $A(x) \Rightarrow C$ then $(\exists xA(x)) \Rightarrow (C)$ and
if $C \Rightarrow A(x)$ then $(C) \Rightarrow (\forall xA(x))$ where $C$ does not contain variable $x$ free.

I tried motivating these choices but unfortunately I could not. Because it is a classical predicate calculus I tried considering truth table semantics to somehow see why these results should be valid, but what I found (not sure if correct) is that the following results are semantically valid as well.

If $A(x) \Rightarrow C$ then $(\forall x(A(x)) \Rightarrow (C)$ and also if $C \Rightarrow A(x)$ then $(C) \Rightarrow (\exists x A(x))$ where $C$ again does not contain variable $x$ free.

If this is indeed true then I am confused as one sees that $\exists$ and $\forall$ act in inference rules in exactly the same way while intuitively I would think that these two logical symbols should act differently.

I would appreciate your advice or thoughts about this.

Comment: Using truth tables on first-order logic formulas is invalid. It is expected that you would conclude wrong results like "if $A(x)\Rightarrow C$ then $(\forall x A(x))\Rightarrow C$". Also, there's plenty of material here on this question. You can search it.

Comment: @frabala what do you mean using truth tables on first-order logic formulas is invalid? I agree that it is not philosophically satisfying but invalid? Consider domain consisting of a finite amount of objects. Then certainly you can use truth tables because it is just a mechanical algorithm

Comment: To semantically justify a formula in *propositional* logic, you can use truth tables. But to semantically justify a formula in *predicate* logic you must find a model which consists of a) a universe of objects, from which the variables $x$ take values, and b) a correspondence between the logic connectives and operations over your universe.

Comment: @frabala take finite universe of objects where there are at least two objects. Can you help me please in that case?

Comment: @AlexKruckman if you accept that other two rules of inference are also semantically valid then $\forall$ and $\exists$ act in exactly the same way.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood your question. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: I'm not sure that your "alternative" rule for the universal quantifier is "strong enough" to prove the fundamental Gen Th : "if $\Gamma \vdash A(x)$, then $\Gamma \vdash \forall x A(x)$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The additional rules you give are indeed valid (on non-empty domains). The reason for this is that the implication $\forall x\, A(x) \Rightarrow \exists x\, A(x)$ is valid (on non-empty domains) - if I recall correctly, this is sometimes called "existential import".

So if $A(x) \Rightarrow C$, then we have both $\forall x\, A(x)\Rightarrow \exists x\, A(x)$ and $\exists x\, A(x)\Rightarrow C$, so $\forall x\, A(x)\Rightarrow C$.

And dually, if $C\Rightarrow A(x)$, then we have both $C\Rightarrow \forall x\, A(x)$ and $\forall x\, A(x)\Rightarrow \exists x\, A(x)$, so $C\Rightarrow \exists x\, A(x)$.

But we don't get from this that $\exists$ and $\forall$ "act in exactly the same way", because the rules you've given in your question don't totally capture the meaning of $\exists$ and $\forall$. You need more rules.

I'm not sure what rules Kleene uses, but there are two common approaches:

1. One approach is to also give the converses of your rules: If $\exists x\, A(x)\Rightarrow C$, then $A(x)\Rightarrow C$, and if $C\Rightarrow \forall x\, A(x)$, then $C\Rightarrow A(x)$ (where $x$ is not free in $C$).
2. Another approach is to include the axioms $A(t)\Rightarrow \exists x\, A(x)$ and $\forall x\, A(x)\Rightarrow A(t)$, where $t$ is a term substitutable for $x$.

In either of these approaches, you'll notice that if you try to replace $\exists$ by $\forall$ or vice versa, the rules are obviously not sound.

---

One more comment: The classical approach to first-order logic assumes that every structure has non-empty domain. But this assumption is not universal. If our semantics for first-order logic allows empty domains, then existential import fails: If there are no $x$s, then $\forall x\, A(x)$ is vacuously true, while $\exists x\, A(x)$ is false.

And similarly, if we allow empty domains, then your versions of the rules where we swap $\exists$ and $\forall$ are no longer valid. Frabala's answer gives a very nice intuitive example of this.

Comment: Great, thanks! Do I understand correctly that you say that "if $\forall x A(x) \Rightarrow C$ then $A(x) \Rightarrow C$" is not sound? I am not sure I understand that

Comment: Correct. The first means "if $A$ is true for all $x$, then $C$ is true", while the latter means "for all $x$, if $A$ is true, then $C$ is true". So for example let $C$ be a contradiction, and let $A$ be a predicate which is true for some but not all $x$. Then the first implication is true, but the second is not.

Answer (score 3):

An intuitive answer, in a world of match sticks and fire and no magic, i.e. one can not make fire out of nothing.

Consider a variable $x$ to mean a match stick. Let $A(x)$ mean "Stick $x$ smokes" and $C$ mean "There is fire".

The rule "if $A(x)\Rightarrow C$ then $(\exists x A(x))\Rightarrow C$" states the very obvious: "if stick x smokes then there's fire" means "if there is some stick $x$ that smokes, then there's fire". This sentence holds in any universe of match sticks.

Now, consider your rule "if $A(x)\Rightarrow C$ then $(\forall x A(x))\Rightarrow C$". It states the following: "if stick x smokes, then there's fire" means also that "if all sticks $x$ are smoking, then there's fire". This derivation is valid only in models that contain at least one object. Because in an empty universe that has no match sticks, all match sticks (which are actually none) are smoking. However, there can be no fire without match sticks!

Comment: Nice example illustrating the point about existential import and empty domains in my answer.

Comment: @frabala do I understand correctly that whenever I have at least one object in my domain then all four of my stated inference rules hold?

Comment: @DanielsKrimans I guess you could add your extra rules as inference rules, although as Alex Kruckman shows in his answer, those extra rules can be derived by the original two rules plus the axiom $\forall x A(x)\Rightarrow \exists x A(x)$. So you only need to add that axiom.

Comment: @frabala Thank you very much for your answer, I appreciate your time!